# How did go net.LookupIP work with Base 8 （octal ）？

Tags: go

SSRF vul should forbidden local ip request.
How did go  net.LookupIP work with Base 8 （octal ）？

```
#go code
net.LookupIP("0177.0.0.01") // NOT_OK  0177.0.0.01
net.LookupIP("0266.075.0310.07") // OK 182.61.200.7

#shell
ping 0177.0.0.01 //OK 127.0.0.1
ping 0266.075.0310.07 // OK 182.61.200.7

input http:address to chrome is the same as ping ,but go not stablize
```

[debug-snapshot-img net.LookupIP("0177.0.0.01") Has Not Decode Base8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrWiH.png)

[debug-snapshot-img  ping 0177.0.0.01 in shell Has Decode Base8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sdr7W.png)

[debug-snapshot-img  net.LookupIP("0266.075.0310.07") Has Decode Base8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGM9x.png)

Comment: Please edit your question to include actual text rather than images. [Here's why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/720999).

Comment: Also, remember to look at the preview when you post - at the moment, your question reads "enter image description here enter image description here enter image description here", which isn't very useful.

Comment: It`s my first question on stack overflow.  Thank you very much for your suggest. I have reedited my question.

Answer (score 0):

### The problem

I think you cannot for a simple reason: that `A.B.C.D` format of IPv4 addresses is called ["dot-decimal"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot-decimal_notation) (or "dotted-decimal") for a reason: the numbers representing the octets of an address are in the decimal format, and no "special modifiers"—such as `0x`, `0`, `0o` etc—to make it "not decimal" are allowed.

I'm inclined to think that the fact `ping` is OK to parse the address with some octets in octal is some weird artefact of its implementation; for instance, it also parses hexadecimal:

```
$ ping 0xAB.0.0.0x01
PING 0xAB.0.0.0x01 (171.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
```

Also note that there's no such thing as "the standard `ping` tool": any OS can have any implementation of it; for instance, `ping` available on Windows definitely shares no source code with `ping` available on a typical GNU/Linux-based OS, and that one is probably different from `ping` implementations available on systems tracing their heritage to *BSD.

To further illustrate my point, consider `host`:

```
$ host -t PTR 0177.0.0.01
Host 0177.0.0.01 not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

This tool, as you can see, failed to cope with the leading `0`s.

So, I think it's sensible to assume that the fact `net.LookupIP` (and `net.ParseIP` for that matter) definitely cannot be blamed for not supporting "octals" when they parse the dotted-decimal representation of an IPv4 address.

### Possible solutions

Possible solutions depend on what really you're after.
If you have to accept IP addresses as strings in such a "dotted-not-so-decimal" format, I'd propose to write a simplistic custom parser which would "preprocess" the strings before calling `net.LookupIP` on them.

Such a preprocessor would split the string and try to parse each octet, then assemble the address back.
Go has `strconv.ParseInt` in its standard library, which accepts the "base" argument telling it which base the digits forming the string representation to parse are, and if you pass 0 as the base, the function uses the usual heuristics to guess the base; in particular, the leading `0` signalizes the base 8—just as you'd want it to.

So, we could roll something like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func normalizeIPv4Addr(s string) (string, error) {
    parts := strings.SplitN(s, ".", 4)
    if len(parts) != 4 || strings.IndexByte(parts[3], '.') != -1 {
        return "", errors.New("invalid IPv4 address: invalid number of octets")
    }

    var dst [4]byte
    for i, p := range parts {
        n, err := strconv.ParseInt(p, 0, 8)
        if err != nil {
            return "", fmt.Errorf("invalid IPv4 address: invalid octet %d: %s", i+1, err)
        }
        if n < 0 || 255 < n {
            return "", fmt.Errorf("invalid IPv4 address: invalid octet %d: out of range", i+1)
        }
        dst[i] = byte(n)
    }

    return net.IP(dst[:]).String(), nil
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(normalizeIPv4Addr("0177.0.0.01"))
}
```

[Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/_jGJS8pjOCa).